# How to change color on a specific app variant in Android Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I was used to override XML resources in values within specific app variants but i cannot do that anymore in jetpack compose so i was wondering which is a good approach with the new library without using any XML at all.

My theming is in a module and that module doesn't know anything about the app variants and i would like it to stay so. Which means that i cannot create a AppVariantColors class for each variant since i would not be able to reference it.

Should i pass the palette to the theme composable?

EDIT: what i am doing now is the following:

First i define a palette class with a set of color variants i will then use in the real variants:

```
enum class AppColorPalette {
    DARK_BLUE,
    DARK_RED,
    LIGHT_BLUE,
    LIGHT_RED
}
```

Then i create an app theme passing the palette

```
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    dims: AppDims = appDims(),
    palette: AppColorPalette = AppColorPalette.DARK_BLUE,
    colors: AppColors = appColors(colorPalette = palette),
    typography: AppTypography = appTypography(colors, dims),
    shapes: AppShapes = appShapes(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalAppColors provides colors,
        LocalAppDims provides dims,
        LocalAppShapes provides shapes,
        LocalAppTypography provides typography,
    ) {
        MaterialTheme(
            colors = colors.materialColors,
            typography = typography.materialTypography,
            shapes = shapes.materialShapes,
            content = content,
        )
    }
}
```

Finally i create app Colors composable based on the palette

```
@Composable
fun appColors(colorPalette: AppColorPalette): AppColors = when (colorPalette) {
    AppColorPalette.DARK_BLUE -> darkAppColorsBlueVariant
    ...
}
```

Where colors are defined something like this:

```
private val darkAppColorsBlueVariant = darkAppColors.copy(
    highEmphasis = AppColorsPalette.WhiteA100,
    midEmphasis = AppColorsPalette.WhiteA50,
    materialColors = darkColors(
        primary = AppColorsPalette.DarkGrey900,
    )
)
```

Basically doing so i can use the BuildConfig approach having to just select the color variant based on the theme

Comment: and what's the problem with your current approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same approach.
Just config your build variant or product flavor in the build.gradle file then in your module define the `MaterialTheme` object (using for example the `Themes.kt` file in the different modules):

```
MaterialTheme(
    colors = …,
    typography = …,
    shapes = …
) {
    // app content
}
```

Or use your approach described in the updated question, using a single MaterialTheme object with the different colors defined in the single variants.

Comment: Indeed but that would mean having a lot of redundancy because i would have to define the MaterialTheme class in every single variant. I will edit the answer with what i have now.

Comment: So right now i will go by defining different generic color flavours in the theme (blue/red/green) and then select those based on the variant, that allows me to avoid having theming code outside of the theme module and the theme module doesnt need to know anything about variants

Comment: You can also define only one MaterialTheme object as described in your question applying different colors defined in single variants.

Comment: Then how would you define the colors in different variants assuming theming is in a module and doesnt know anything about that? Its not like XML where you can override an existing XML

Comment: I am missing the point. How can you override the existing XML if you don't know anything about that? I'm going to expand my example but it is the same of the XML approach.

Comment: I dont want to use XML at all, i think the approach i am now using (the one i added in the original question) works, so define different color variants in the theme using Kotlin then based on the variant select the palette in the activity setting the theme

Comment: @FrankMonza So you're saying that the edit you added to your question is the answer? Then it should be moved from the question to an answer.

Comment: Its what i am doing i dont know if its a good approach

Answer (score 0):

One way could be through `BuildConfig` fields on your `build.gradle` (app)  file.

First define your flavors:

```
android {
  // other stuff
  flavorDimensions "base"
  productFlavors {
    cocacola {
      dimension "base"
      // cocacola is red :)
      buildConfigField "int", "accentColor", "0xFF0000"
    }
    pepsi {
      dimension "base"
      // pepsi is blue
      buildConfigField "int", "accentColor", "0x00FF00"
    }

  }
}
```

This will autogenerate a `BuildConfig.java` that you can access through Kotlin:

```java
public final class BulildConfig {
  public static final int accentColor = 0xFF000; // depending on the flavor built
}
```

Then you can reference this static values from the place you define the material theme similar to how @Philip Dukov suggested

```kotlin
private val AppPalette = lightColors(
    accent = Color(BuildConfig.accentColor)
)

MaterialTheme(
    colors = AppPalette,
    typography = …,
    shapes = …,
    content = …
)
```

Comment: I have extended this a bit in the example i gave in the question by using the flavour to select a palette instead

Comment: Yeah… defining an entire theme using gradle might be a little bit of a hell… better have them all defined in kotlin and select the proper one at runtime :)